# How can I start the Thieves Guild quests if Brynolf is hiding from me?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, xbox-360

I have just kind of learned about the Nightingale armor and how cool it is an all. I figured out I have to complete the Thieves Guild quest line.

I went into my quests and do not see a quest on the list of quests I found for the specific quest line. Here is my problem. I have joined the guild, but that was a long time ago. I have no clue weather I succeeded in planting the ring or not. In addition, no matter where I look, I can not find Brynjolf in Riften. Is there any way I can still start these quests?

Also, all of the odd jobs I ask for are auxiliary quests except the "No Stone Unturned" quest and I only need Proudspire Manor to complete that quest. Is that another way to access the main quest line?

Answer (score 4):

[Brynjolf](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Brynjolf) won't be in Riften proper once you do the initial ring-planting quest ([A Chance Arrangement](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:A_Chance_Arrangement)). He moves to the [Ratway](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Ratway) once you finish the quest (successfully or not; failing to plant the ring does not prevent you from joining the guild).

If you can't find him in Riften's market or the Bee and Barb, and you can't find him in the Ratway, you may have encountered a bug.